# How can I download and save files by create a Safari/Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, safari-extension

I want to build a Safari/Chrome Extension to download multiple files and save them in a batch way. But it seems that I couldn't do it by JavaScript only, because of the security reasons. So is there any way, for example, Extension API, can meet my need?

Comment: I know there is a storage API, don't know if it is what you need https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage

Comment: it seems only works on Chrome...but what about Safari? @Aigzy

Comment: Well I guess they all have a different API. I have only developed chromes extensions, I can't really help you more

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! @Aigzy